# Menu within a dialog fragment

Tags: android

I have a custom dialog fragment I've created that i'd like to have the toolbar and a menu of options. Ultimately i'd like it to look and behave just like the send feedback option in the Google Maps app. I've got the toolbar working (except the back button) and I've designed what i'd like the menu to look like, however i'm not sure how to get the items in the menu to become clickable. My question is how exactly do I make each menu option clickable and take you to another activity or intent.

Since I just created a Stack Overflow account (longtime lurker, first time posting) I cant post images to show, therefore here's the link on imgur of what I mean:

[My apps help & feedback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zspUE.png)

[Google Maps help & feedback with "Report a mapping issue" button held down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrwVS.png)

My help xml file:

```
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="60dp"
        android:paddingRight="60dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp"
            android:tint="#727272" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/about_title"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:text="@string/about_description"
                android:textColor="#727272"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/about"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="60dp"
        android:paddingRight="60dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_help_black_24dp"
            android:tint="#727272" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/get_help_title"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:text="@string/get_help_description"
                android:textColor="#727272"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapissue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/help"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="60dp"
        android:paddingRight="60dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_map_black_24dp"
            android:tint="#727272" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/report_map_issue_title"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:text="@string/report_map_issue_description"
                android:textColor="#727272"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/appfeedback"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/mapissue"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="60dp"
        android:paddingRight="60dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_feedback_black_24dp"
            android:tint="#727272" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/send_app_feedback_title"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="28dp"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:text="@string/send_app_feedback_description"
                android:textColor="#727272"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

My help dialog java file:

```
package team6.iguide;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;

public class Help extends DialogFragment {

    public Help() {
        // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the main view
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.help, container, false);

        // Initiate toolbar within dialog
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        // Add title to toolbar
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.help);
        // Add back button to dialog
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);

        toolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //onCancel(DialogInterface dialog);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        // Request a window without the title
        dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

I'm new to android development so if someone could at least guide me in the right direction, i'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned a ton about Android since I first asked this question so I figured i'd answer this in case anyone else new comes across it. To accomplish what I wanted I ended up having to create a ListView within a Dialog. To see my code you can check it out within my [App on Github](https://github.com/cammace/iGuide). The three java classes are:

Help
HelpMenuItem
HelpMenuAdapter